# Auto Populate Combox1 and ListBox1 from Workseet

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, listboxitem

I am trying to connect my NIGOcomboBox list with the ListBox1 list on my worksheet (DropDownMenus).  Currently I have the NIGOcomboBox populating from

```
 Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 Dim cell As Range

'Populate NIGO dropdown menu from "DropDownMenus worksheet.
 For Each cell In .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
 If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then NIGOcombobox.AddItem cell.Value
 Next cell
 End With
```

Then I have a ListBox that populates as follows:

```
 Private Sub NIGOcombobox_Change()

 With Worksheets("DropDownMenus")
 .Activate
 Select Case NIGOcombobox
 'Populate NIGO Reason list by dropdown menu selection.
 Case "AMRF"
  For Each cell In .Range("C3:C" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row)
  If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then ListBox1.AddItem cell.Value
 Next cell

 Case "OATS"
  For Each cell In .Range("D3:C" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row)
  If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then ListBox1.AddItem cell.Value
 Next cell

 Case Else
  MsgBox "Please select a NIGO Reason"

 End Select
 End With
 End Sub
```

Its not exactly working as planned.  I need to make this so when the next person comes along to add a new item to the NIGOcombox it auto selects the next row so they do not have t adjust the code.


Example 

NIGOCombobox is in sheet (DropDownMenus) column ("A2:A") and the ListBox1 is also on sheet (DropDownMenus) but starts on column ("C3:C"). Each column after - D, E, F G etc. correspond with the next NIGOCombobox item.

So, A2 =("C3:C"), B2 =("D3:D), C2 = ("E3:D") and so on.  Than way when a new item is entered into the NIGOCombobox it auto attaches to the next Listbox row.
Hope this makes sense! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure of your aim. The following code will load column B in `NIGOcombobox` and then seach for the selected value in the first row of `Worksheets("DropDownMenus")`. So, if you transpose your column B into the first row of `Worksheets("DropDownMenus")` (starting in C1), that row will behave like a "header", and this might work. PS: if you want to add to previously selected items, delete the line `ListBox1.Clear`

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim cell As Range

    'Populate NIGO dropdown menu from "DropDownMenus worksheet.
    For Each cell In Worksheets("DropDownMenus").Range("B2:B" & Worksheets("DropDownMenus").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then NIGOcombobox.AddItem cell.Value
    Next cell

End Sub

Private Sub NIGOcombobox_Change()
    Dim TheValueInCombobox As String
    Dim TheHeader As Range
    Dim TheHeaderColumn As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long

    ListBox1.Clear
    TheValueInCombobox = NIGOcombobox.Value
    Set TheHeader = Worksheets("DropDownMenus").Range("A1:Z1").Find(TheValueInCombobox) 'You might want to expand the range
    TheHeaderColumn = TheHeader.Column
    LastRow = Worksheets("DropDownMenus").Cells(Rows.Count, TheHeaderColumn).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each cell In Worksheets("DropDownMenus").Range(Cells(3, TheHeaderColumn), Cells(LastRow, TheHeaderColumn))
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then ListBox1.AddItem cell.Value
    Next cell

End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

There is no need to have the values for populating `NIGOcombobox` in a dedicated column: you can scan the headers directly. This way data structure would be clearer (I think).

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim cell As Range
Dim lColumn As Long

    'Populate NIGO dropdown menu from "DropDownMenus worksheet.
    lColumn = Worksheets("DropDownMenus").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For Each cell In Worksheets("DropDownMenus").Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(1, lColumn))
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then NIGOcombobox.AddItem cell.Value
    Next cell

End Sub

Private Sub NIGOcombobox_Change()
    Dim TheValueInCombobox As String
    Dim TheHeader As Range
    Dim TheHeaderColumn As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim lColumn As Long

    ListBox1.Clear
    TheValueInCombobox = NIGOcombobox.Value
    lColumn = Worksheets("DropDownMenus").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set TheHeader = Worksheets("DropDownMenus").Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(1, lColumn)).Find(TheValueInCombobox)
    TheHeaderColumn = TheHeader.Column
    LastRow = Worksheets("DropDownMenus").Cells(Rows.Count, TheHeaderColumn).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each cell In Worksheets("DropDownMenus").Range(Cells(3, TheHeaderColumn), Cells(LastRow, TheHeaderColumn))
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then ListBox1.AddItem cell.Value
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: This is giving me an error for TheHeaderColumn = TheHeader.Column. Error = "Object variable or With variable not set"?

Comment: All the values that you have in column B must be in the first row. For example, if B2=AMRF, B3=OATS, B4=LITTLE and B5=SMALL, then C1 must be AMRF, D1=OATS, E1=LITTLE  and F1=SMALL

Comment: In your code, you have hardcoded the relations: AMRF correspond to Column C, OATS to column D, and so on. This can be tedious if you have many items. In the code above, the "selectable" items are also columns headers...

Comment: I know I'm not suppose to say thank, but Perfection! Thank you so much!